# Cannot bulk load. The file does not exist or you don't have file access rights. Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

everyone. I am quite a new user of Azure Data Studio and stumbled upon the following problem:

I was intending to read the CSV formatted file from SQL and take the data therefrom. Here is my SQL Code:

```
USE excel_checks
BULK INSERT short_info from '/Item.csv' 
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '/n');
```

I tried to change the location of the file to the docker container by entering the following code in my Terminal

```
docker cp /Users/office/Desktop/Item.csv name of my container:/
```

It throws the following error: **Cannot bulk load. The file "/Item.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.**
I would be happy of someone could help me get this issue sorted out. Googling did not help much as I keep getting the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: Azure SQL Database only supports reading from Azure Blob Storage.

After having read the documentation, I saw the following note. Quite confusing, is there any workaround?

Comment: I don't think the Azure SQL Database tag applies here since it seems SQL Server is running in a Linux container.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying the file to the root of the file system, copy it into a sub directory to avoid the file access right issue:

```
docker cp /Users/office/Desktop/Item.csv name of my container:/tmp
```

Then run the BULK INSERT with that path:

```
USE excel_checks
BULK INSERT short_info from '/tmp//Item.csv' 
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '/n');
```